# How to watch for a new element on a page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I want to run the following code whenever a new "div" element is added to the page:

```js
  const divTags = document.getElementsByTagName('div')
  for (const tag of divTags) {
    console.log(tag)
  }
```

What are some ways of accomplishing this?

Comment: [Mutation Observers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) might come in handy

Comment: @blex that did the trick! Feel free to make this an answer if you like!